# Why does it hang after I upgrade from F22 to F23?

Tags: fedora, boot, upgrade

<sup>This is meant to be a self-answered question.</sup>

Fedora 23 has just been released. I followed the [system upgrade](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/DNF_system_upgrade) instructions from the wiki.

```
sudo dnf update --refresh
# reboot the computer
sudo dnf install dnf-plugin-system-upgrade
sudo dnf system-upgrade download --releasever=23
sudo dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

The upgrade went without a hitch. I saw the new kernel in the boot screen, but whenever I tried to boot into either the F22 or F23 kernels, I get a blinking white cursor after the loading bar is complete. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have an Nvidia card, the issue may be explained by [rpmfusion](http://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia#Determining_your_card_model):

> 'Fedora 23 Users'
>
> nVidia currently doesn't support the Xorg server in Fedora 23, please
>   take a look at the Rawhide section from this document.

In order to boot, you can boot into a console using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, then remove the proprietary driver with:

```
sudo dnf remove xorg-x11-drv-nvidia\*
```

Afterwards, reboot, and everything should work fine. If you then want to try installing the proprietary driver again, follow these instructions from rpmfusion:

> Rawhide kernels are built with debug enabled GPL-only symbols which
>   kernel is incompatible with the nvidia binary-only driver. You need to
>   use the Rawhide nodebug repository.
>
> Please remind that Xorg server version is also to take into
>   consideration. In the case of incompatibilities with the xorg-server,
>   you might need to downgrade to the previous fedora release:
>
> ```
> dnf downgrade xorg-x11-server\* --releasever=22 --allowerasing
> echo "exclude=xorg-x11*" >> /etc/dnf/dnf.conf
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I have had very similar problem: fedora hangs after

```
dnf system-upgrade reboot
```

My solution is:

1. edit grub menu properties, adding `runlevel 3` to line starts with "linux"
2. to use `distro-sync`, not `system-upgrade`:

   ```
   dnf distro-sync --releasever=23
   ```